# Logging in/out of Spring application using Spring Security and CSRF protection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am constructing a Spring web application based off of the Spring Security Hello World examples. I am trying to implement logging in and out through Spring Security. I can log in successfully but cannot log out. The redirect occurs as expected but when the login page tries to load after logout:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

throws:

```
Mar 01, 2016 3:24:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [laughing-robot] in context with 
     path [/laughing-robot] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at line 43.

Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2928)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2298)
```

Here is the logout form in the jsp:

```
                        <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
                        <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
                          <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                        </form>
```

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm happy to provide source files but not sure what is relevant.

**UPDATE:**

I have been trying to set this up via annotations (vs xml configuration). I'm not sure of the advantages/disadvantages of doing this. Here is my `servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.robot.configuration"/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean name="/" class="com.robot.controllers.HelloController" />
</beans>
```

My Login Controller (which I don't think is actually being implemented, set multiple breakpoints here that are never hit.):

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.robot.configuration")
public class LoginController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
}
```

And my Security Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class RobotSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
RobotLoginSuccessHandler robotLoginSuccessHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll() 
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(robotLoginSuccessHandler)
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .logout()                                    
        .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN","USER");
}
```

Comment: Can you show spring-security config file ?

Comment: Updated question with additional files.

Comment: Default configuration expects your roles start with "ROLE_" unless you change rolePrefix of org.springframework.security.vote.RoleVoter. Try adding ROLE_ prefix

Comment: I don't think that applies when using the annotations method. According to [Spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/):

"When creating our users in #1 and #2, we do not specify “ROLE_” as we would with the XML configuration. Since this convention is so common, the “roles” method automatically adds “ROLE_” for you. If you did not want “ROLE_” added you could use the authorities method instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing a class that implemented LogoutSuccessHandler. I copied the methods exactly from the stock LogoutSuccessHandler. I then modified my SecurityConfiguration class to include logout parameters:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll() 
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(robotLoginSuccessHandler)
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .logout()
        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/login?logout").addLogoutHandler(robotLogoutSuccessHandler)
        .permitAll();
}
```

I suppose that since I defined my own configuration class, I needed to specify where exactly I wanted the LogoutHandler to execute.